# Grid World Assigning a Variable for the Number of Cols

Tags: java

I am having difficulty assigning a variable for the number of columns on the grid. I receive an error when I am instantiating the cols variable. Can anyone help me?

```
public void act()
    {

        Location place = getLocation();
        Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
        int cols = gr.getNumCols;
        if (place.getCol() + 1 < cols)
                moveTo(new Location(place.getRow(), place.getCol() + 1));
        else
                moveTo(new Location(place.getRow(), 0));
```

This is the error message I receive.

```
F:\Lab III Car and Teleporter\Car Project\Car.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        int cols = gr.getNumCols;
                     ^
  symbol:   variable getNumCols
  location: variable gr of type Grid<Actor>
1 error

Process completed.
```

Comment: Why not show the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> int cols = gr.getNumCols;

You're missing the paranthesis here.

This line shoulde should be (assuming there is actually a method `getNumCols()`):

> int cols = gr.getNumCols();